# Sending mail from MS outlook to SMTP Server registered in Linux machine

Tags: python, email, outlook

I want to send a mail from my MS Outlook on my Windows machine to the SMTP server on the Linux machine, which is registered by a python script.

Please let me know, is it possible to receive mails sent from MS outlook in python smptd server ?

Comment: It is possible. If your python script can speak proper `SMTP`, then your `MS Outlook` can send email to your python script using `SMTP`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Can you please explain little in details.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to create an [SMTP server](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/96/) using python. Start the server.
- `swaks` is a tool to test `SMTP` protocol. You can use it to deliver a test email to your SMTP Server. The following command will send a test email to your `Python SMTP` server.

  ```
  swaks --from test@example.com --to other@example.org --server localhost
  ```

  You can see the test email written to a file with `eml` extension. This shows that your SMTP server is working.
- Now configure your `MS Outlook` to connect to `localhost` and port `25` and try sending mail. Your SMTP server will write all the incoming emails to files.

Hope that helps.